# custom code for Hover over,Zoom effect, with text into Divi Theme Wordpress code block, No spaces between the blocks

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need some help pronto
**please visit** https://mmmcgaha-vcxd.envatosites.com/ 
to see the sample of what i wish to create in Divi theme code block

Create mine, but not exactly as that, don't know if i can get some help...

Thank you

Below is sample code, am sorry it was a lot, but just had to select post that which i can from my code

```css
#mendo-happy-healthy-header h3 {font-size: 70px;
    color: #4bb3e6;
    font-family: 'lulo_cleanone_bold';
    letter-spacing: -8px;
    line-height: 100px;}
    

    mendo-happy-healthy-header {
 margin-top: -20px !important;}

    .box { height: 274px;
           position: relative;
           overflow: hidden;
           width: 363px;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
        }
  
  

    .box img {position: absolute;
               left: 0;
              -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
              -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
              -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
              -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
              transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     }
 

    .box .overbox { background-color: rgba(28,28,28,0.81);
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    color: #fff;
                    z-index: 100;
                   -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                   -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                   -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                   -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                   transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                   opacity: 0;
                   width: 363px;
                   height: 274px;
                   padding: 130px 20px;
                    }

    .box:hover .overbox { opacity: 1; }
                        .box .overtext {
                        -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                        -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                        -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                        -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                        transition: all 300ms ease-out;
                        transform: translateY(40px);
                       -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);

    .mendo-links { text-transform: lowercase;
                   font-size: 36px;
                   position: relative;
                   color: white;
                   text-shadow: 3px 0 29px rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
                   text-align: center;
                   vertical-align: middle;
                   margin-top: 26%;
                    }
```

```html
<a href="/core-values"><div class="box"><p><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/feature-1-image.jpg" alt="" /></p><h4 class="mendo-links">Copywriting</h4><p><img class="mendo-lines" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LINES2.png" alt="" /></p><div class="overbox"><p></p><div class="title overtext"><p class="mendo-links-title">Copywriting</p></div><div class="tagline overtext"><p class="mendo-links-description">Synth jean shorts try-hard art party meh disrupt, forage offal ugh readymade cronut man braid</p><p class="mendo-links-read-more">+ learn more</p></div></div></div></a>
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: <a href="/core-values"><div class="box"><p><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/feature-1-image.jpg" alt="" /></p><h4 class="mendo-links">Copywriting</h4><p><img class="mendo-lines" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/LINES2.png" alt="" /></p><div class="overbox"><p></p><div class="title overtext"><p class="mendo-links-title">Copywriting</p></div><div class="tagline overtext"><p class="mendo-links-description">Synth jean shorts try-hard art party meh disrupt, forage offal ugh readymade cronut man braid</p><p class="mendo-links-read-more">+ learn more</p></div></div></div></a>